# Use a dll containing an ASP.NET server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I wrote an application that use grpc with ASP.NET client/server.

This application is built for watch and inform about some operations.

Because I would to have an application also compatible with linux, I transformed it in a dll, then for Windows I made a little exe that uses it, with an icon in the systray.

It works for Windows, I must test for linux except for a part, I would to get the addresses used by the server after launching... it works if I back the dll in console mode, but with the short "launcher" it's impossible (add by edit) to get the addresses with the code i wrote between balises, BUT you can connect to the server (by example i changed port in config file to verify if it was not an address by default and it works.). **My problem is only to retrieve addresses** after launch, i need them to add the possibility to receive a mail with addresses to connect, show them in systray..

Yesterday I found this way to get addresses used:

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,...)
  {
      string ServerAddress = app.ServerFeatures.Get<IServerAddressesFeature().Addresses.FirstOrDefault();
      // ---
  }
```

with the short launcher the string is null while it works when I back transform the dll as a program and launch it.

I would to have an easy way, without to make big modifications when I make an app for a system or another, I have chosen what was the more compatible and would to stay in this way if possible. I know i could make an identifier to know on which system I then launch according to the OS, but i hoped to find another way in case I want to make something else with this app.

Edit: 
It seems it could be a problem between the fact to launch a systray that launch Kestrel. I'm beginner with Asp .net. I copy/paste contract and constructor to the systray, it seems i have the same problem (i used a different port). I can connect but IApplicationBuilder don't have the list of adresses used.

Comment: See https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/956

Comment: i made a wrong explanation of my problem, i will edit